# Wcf webservice output not changing

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, service

I have create a wcf service that contain a function getData that return Hello, i have changes the text Hello to Helloworld but the service output is same how we can make changes in service output or it takes value from anywhere else ? Please help me

Comment: Did you recompile your service dlls after modifying the code?

Comment: You mean build the code ?

Comment: yes, this may be one reason.

Comment: yes you need to rebuild. When you only change code the web machine is still running the last compiled execution you did. When you rebuild the web instance will shutdown and a new one will start with latest build

Comment: I have build the whole code and upload on the server but is gives me the same result. Will i have to make any update in server(Host), to make changes

Comment: I hope you mean uploaded updated service. Right? If yes, then can you test that service using wcf test client https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.110).aspx and check if that is giving correct result?

Comment: I got error in wcf test client. Is it require to make changes @amit

Comment: if you changed the signature of a method (parameters, method name) or added new things you will need to update the web reference on the client app. Simply right click on the web service in the web reference and update web reference.

Comment: @Franck - You are right but checking with WCF test client itself producing errors. Means, there is issue with Service first.

Comment: I have run the service in localhost it work fine but previous unchanged output. And in wcf test client only service added successfully message display. I want to know that the is how many way to compile while code.

Comment: I have also added break point to this function but the control is reach there

Answer (score -1):

You have to update the webReferences:

Step:

Right click on App_WebReferences -> Update web References